# How to specifiy default CSS class for list <ul> in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

In TinyMCE, how can I pre-define CSS class for unordered list `<ul>`.

The idea is that I write my article in TinyMCE editor, then once the content is saved, the final HTML is:

```
<ul class="class_a">
...
</ul>
```

I'm using `django-tinymce`.

Comment: Do you want this class to be added to every `<ul>` without exception, or do you want this to be the default *option*, but allow for other markup?

Comment: @TinyLincoln Of course it would be perfect if this is the default option with the possibility to change BUT also the option to add this to every <ul> without exception is fine for me at this point...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution seems to create a plugin, but it's very complex to keep the DOM values. So I found this alternative solution.

1. Style the default `ul` and `ol` in your CSS (put `class_a` styles into them, without class applied)
2. Add `styleselect` in your TinyMCE toolbar
3. Add `style_formats` option to style your ul and ol like this for example:

   ```
   style_formats: [
        { title: 'Unstyled list', selector: 'ul,ol', classes: 'list-none' }
    ]
   ```